# libGDX button layout with no spacing

Tags: libgdx

I'm using a table to layout my menu buttons, but the spacing between buttons is big enough to drive a car through.  What can I do to gain more control over the apparent cell padding? I've searched StackOverflow posts, read through the API, typed '.' after table and actor to browse the autocompletes, manually adjusted values in the skin file, and looked at other people's projects on Github.  Some of the methods I've tried include sizeBy(), scaleBy(), pad(), setFillParent(), space(), fillY(), and grow()

A helpful answer would describe how to get buttons to stack on top of each other, touching.

```
Gdx.input.setInputProcessor(stage); 
// Create a table that fills the screen. Everything else will go inside this table.
Table table = new Table();
table.setFillParent(true);
table.setDebug(true);
stage.addActor(table);

table.setBackground(new TiledDrawable(background));

//create buttons
TextButton newGame = new TextButton("New Game", skin);
TextButton preferences = new TextButton("Preferences", skin);
TextButton exit = new TextButton("Exit", skin);


TextButtonStyle tbs = new TextButtonStyle(newGame.getStyle());
NinePatch np = new NinePatch(skin.getPatch("button"));
np.setColor(np.getColor().sub(0f, 0f, 0f, .4f)); 
tbs.up = new NinePatchDrawable(np);
newGame.setStyle(tbs);        
preferences.setStyle(tbs);
exit.setStyle(tbs);


table.bottom().right().padBottom(40f).padRight(40f);

//add buttons to table
table.add(newGame).bottom().right().fillX().uniformX();
table.row();//.pad(1, 0, 1, 0);
table.add(preferences).bottom().right().fillX().uniformX();
table.row();
table.add(exit).bottom().right().fillX().uniformX();
```

Answer (score 0):

It was my skin.  I used the sample "Rusty Robot UI", but it doesn't crop it's button images tightly.  Tried another one and saw the stacking I was looking for.